Practical example of paramattha dhamma compared to samutti
Please give a clear simple example of how this looks in a practical way without quoting suttas. I just want a practical example. Thanks
"The object of consciousness, or mind-object, that arises has to be of ultimate reality, not conventional reality. We must be able to differentiate between what is absolute reality, or paramattha dhamma and what is conventional reality, or sammuti."

Where did you quoted "The object of consciousness, or mind-object... from? It looks wrong. that arises has to be of ultimate reality, how a thought is ultimate reality?

Ultimate reality is viewing the picture below as merely elements (dhatu); or merely aggregates (khandha); or merely a sense object (ayatana); which is impermanent; unsatisfactory & not-self.
Samutti is viewing the picture below as "Donald Trump", "evil man", "world saviour", etc.


So how would that apply as far as meditation goes? because the quote that I gave was referring to that.   Would it mean that when a thought arises knowing it as phenomena arising and passing? Also when a sensation or feeling arises

samutti is thoughts about "self" (internal & external). paramattha  is no thoughts of self
